# How to find the voltage of the coil in this RLC Circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, impedance, coil, equation

[image: ![Trying to find the voltage of L1 in the circuit above]
I am looking for the voltage of L1. What I tried to do is this:
Vsource = I(R1+R2+1/iwC1+iwL1+iwL2)  Equation 1
Vsource = IR1+IR2+Q/C1+L1dI/dt+L2dI/dt  Equation 2
Equating 1 and 2, I(R1+R2+1/iwC1+iwL1+iwL2) = IR1+IR2+Q/C1+L1dI/dt+L2dI/dt
Solving for I, I get I=(dI/dt*(L1+L2)+Q/C)/(1/iwC1+iw(L1+L2))
Then to find the voltage of L2, I multiply this expression for current by the impedance of the coil, and for dI/dt I substitute I*i*w*e^iwt
Is this method valid?

Comment: You are over-complicating things by not thinking about circuit simplification. It's a series tuned RLC circuit and formulas are plenty on the net.

Comment: Why am I overcomplicating it? I didn't find any other formula and don't really know how I could simplify the circuit further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) we can write:

$$\text{V}_{\text{L}_1}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{sL}_1\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{source}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{sL}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}_2}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Which gives, using [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_{\text{L}_1}\left(t\right)&=\text{L}_1\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{source}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{sL}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}_2}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\right)\\
\\
&=\text{L}_1\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{source}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{sL}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}_2}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\right)\\
\\
&=\text{L}_1\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{source}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{sL}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}_2}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\right)
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am not familiar with Laplace transforms. Do you think my original solution holds or would your solution using Laplace transforms be better (and if so, why?)

Comment: @Hug's It's worth taking the time to learn how to use the Laplace transform, though it's far from necessary for a circuit this simple.

Comment: @Hearth, How would you go about solving for the voltage in the coil though?

Answer (score 0):

After transforming the circuit according to Laplace and assuming that there are no mutual inductances (shielded coils), I calculated the Laplace transform of the current, then I determined the required voltages by applying the generalized Ohm's law. Having done this I determined the phasors in sinusoidal regime of the required voltages.
[image]